# Why am I getting an Unauthorized response with the Outlook API with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a task that will retrieve the messages in outlook mail with Microsoft **Azure** Active Directory.

I setup my azure account. Register an app, add certificate then add user to my AD. My signin method returns an access token which means signin is successful and pass the access token to outlook messages API. but the Outlook messages API returns unauthorize.

Here is my scope: email Group.Read.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.ReadWrite

I used Laravel HTTP Client to send request. Hope anyone can help me, Im stuck on this problem for week

```
     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->params = [
             'client_id'       => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
             'scope'           => env('OAUTH_SCOPES'),
             'client_secret'   => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
             'username'        => 'xxxxxxxx@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com',
             'password'        => 'xxxxxxxx',
             'grant_type'      => 'password',
             'redirectUri'     => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
             'urlAuthorize'    => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
             'urlAccessToken'  => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
             'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
          ];
      }
      public function signin()
      {
          $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token';
          $response = Http::asForm()->post($url, $this->params);
          if($response->ok()){
               $returnData = $response->json();
               $mail_api = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages';
               $messagesResponse = Http::withToken($returnData['access_token'])->get($mail_api);
               dd($messagesResponse);
          }
       }
```

Here is the response of my signin. I used Laravel HTTP client to send request.

[image]

And for additinal info in my granted permission
[image]

Comment: "Active Directory" and "Azure Active Directory" are completely unrelated - the fact they share a name is confusing for everyone. I'm editing your question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: You need to edit your screenshot to not show your Bearer token. That's sensitive information.

Comment: thx for feedback and clarification @Dai. I'm referring to Azure Active Directory

Comment: What value are you using for `OAUTH_SCOPES` ?

Comment: @Dai I update my post for scope and permissions granted

Answer (score 0):

It has mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#get-a-message-collection). One of the following permissions is required to call this API:

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail.read
wl.imap
```

And the permissions in your issue like Mail.Read, Mail.Read.Shared, Mail.ReadBasic are used for Microsoft Graph API, such as [Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API.